# W3C Error: X-UA-Compatible HTTP header must have the value IE=edge, was IE=Edge,chrome=1

Tags: w3c-validation

I have this error from W3C Tool...

I changed my code from

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

but the tools still show me the same error message...

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I have changed it in the HTML files but doesn't work, When I fixed it in .htaccees file it works, very strange :)

Old code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

New code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

And everything is working perfect now :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution...

I must change this in .htaccess file too...